# Perl Arrays and grep

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, text, grep

I think its more a charachters, anyway, I have a text file, consisted of something like that:

```
COMPANY NAME

    City

    Addresss,
     Address number

    Email 

    phone number
```

and so on... (it repeats itself, but with different data...), lets assume thing text is now in $strting variable.

I want to have an array (@row), for example:

```
$row[0] = "COMPANY NAME";
$row[1] = "City";
$row[2] = "Addresss,
              Address number";
$row[3] = "Email";
$row[4] = "phone number";
```

At first I though, well thats easily can be done with grep, something like that:
1) `@rwo = grep (/^^$/, $string);`
No GO!
2) `@row = grep (/\n/, $string);`

still no go, tried also with split and such, still no go.
any idea?
thanks,

Comment: Since "it repeats itself, but with different data" are you not instead looking for an array of these companies' data, like @companies = ( { name => 'COMPANY NAME', address => 'Address, Address number', ...}, { name => 'ANOTHER COMPANY', address => 'Some other address', ...} ); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
 use warnings;
 my $string = "COMPANY NAME

        City

        Addresss,
         Address number

        Email

        phone number";

    my @string_parts = split /\n\n+/, $string; 
    foreach my $test (@string_parts){
          print"$test\n";
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
COMPANY NAME
City
Addresss,
Address number 
Email
phone number
```

Comment: Doesn't work, OP wants Address and Address number in the same part.

Answer (score 6):

FM has given an answer that works using split, but I wanted to point out that Perl makes this really easy if you're reading this data from a filehandle. All you need to do is to set the special variable $/ to an empty string. This puts Perl into "paragraph mode". In this mode each record returned by the file input operator will contain a paragraph of text rather than the usual line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

local $/ = '';

my @row = <DATA>;

chomp @row;

print Dumper(\@row);

__DATA__
COMPANY NAME

City

Addresss,
 Address number

Email 

phone number
```

The output is:

```
$ ./addr 
$VAR1 = [
          'COMPANY NAME',
          'City',
          'Addresss,
 Address number',
          'Email ',
          'phone number'
        ];
```

Comment: Since you can open a scalar as a filehandle, it's pretty easy to apply this trick to any data.  `open my $fh, '<', \$data;`

Answer (score 5):

The way I understand your question, you want to grab the items separated by at least one blank line. Although `/\n{2,}/` would be correct in a literal sense (split on one or more newlines), I would suggest the regex below, because it will handle *nearly blank* lines (those containing only whitespace characters).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'COMPANY NAME

City

Addresss,
 Address number

Email 

phone number';

my @items = split /\n\s*\n/, $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) cannot take a string as an argument.

This is why you need to [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the string on the token that you're after (as [FM shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634280/perl-arrays-and-grep/3634307#3634307)).

While it isn't clear what you need this for, I would strongly recommend considering the [`Tie::File`](http://search.cpan.org/~mjd/Tie-File-0.96/lib/Tie/File.pm) module: